# Can't execute Retrofit sync operation by Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2.6

In my android app:

app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.0"
```

In my interface:

```
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query


interface MyRestClient {

    @GET("/event")
    suspend fun getEvents(@Query("orgn") base: Int, @Query("event") quote: Int): Response<List<Event>>
}
```

And I want to call this method **synchronously**.

So I try this:

```
    import retrofit2.Call
    import retrofit2.Response

    class TransportService {
        companion object {
            private val myRestClient =
                RestClientFactory.createRestClient(MyRestClient ::class.java)

            suspend fun getEventSync(orgn: Int, event: Int): Response<*> {
                val call: Call<*> = myRestClient .getEvents(orgn, event)      
                   return call.execute()
                }
```

And call by this:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val response = TransportService.getEvents(100, 200)
```

But  I get compile error in this line:

```
val call: Call<*> = myRestClient.getEvents(orgn, event)
```

error is:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is Response<List<Event>> but Call<*> was expected
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you the problem.

```
val call: Call<*> = myRestClient.getEvents(orgn, event)
```

`getEvents` returns `Response<List<Event>>` but you are trying to assign it to `Call<*>`.

With retrofit 2.6 and Coroutines you no longer need Call.

The `getEventSync` function no longer makes sense. You can decide between sync and async at the invocation spot. For blocking:

```
val events: Reponse<List<Event>> = runBlocking {
        myRestClient.getEvents(orgn, event)
}
```

Comment: I added my answer

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `Response` type in your `MyRestClient` interface, but expecting a `Call` in your `TransportService`.

In your `TransportService` class, change the parameter type of `val call` from `Call<*>` to `Response<List<Event>>`.

Also, since you want to execute this method synchronously, you probably don't need the `suspend` modifier on your `getEvents` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
 viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "step_1")
            TransportService.getEvents(100, 200)
            Debug.d(TAG, "step_2")
            TransportService.getEvents(300, 400)
            Debug.d(TAG, "step_3")
            TransportService.getEvents(500, 600)
            Debug.d(TAG, "step_4")
        }
```

in TransportService.kt

```
suspend fun getEvents(
            orgn: Int,
            event: Int
        ): Response<*> {
            return  waitressCallRestClient.getEvents(orgn, event)
        }
```

In interface:

```
@GET("/event")
    suspend fun getEvents(@Query("orgn") base: Int, @Query("event") quote: Int): Response<List<Event>>
```

Because I use **retrofit 2.6** and `suspend` function as result **step_2** print only after finish `TransportService.getEvents(100, 200)`.
And **step_2** print only after finish  `TransportService.getEvents(300, 400)` and so on.

So this is what I need. I has synchronously call of `getEvents()`